# elsevier class error

Tags: lyx, elsarticle

I've been trying LateX and Lyx out for a few days. Lyx is really a help for a new-comer and I had few troubles so far, except for some unknown errors when I was configuring elsarticle documentclass.

I have installed Lyx, MacTex 2012, and already put the `elsarticle` bundle into `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-local` and reconfigured Lyx. Then I tried selecting `elsarticle` in Lyx and the exported TeX code in Texmaker. They both gave error information.

Here is a picture of the error info:

[image: link]
<sub>(source: [wordpress.com](https://wordsterence.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/screen-shot-2012-12-18-at-12-07-10-pm.png))</sub>

The file in first line is `hyperref.sty` under `texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref`.

```
%% LyX 2.0.5 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
sds
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On [LaTeX-Community.org](http://www.latex-community.org/) we had the very same error message in [elsarticle | Problem with 'hyperref' Package](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=14622). There, the OP solved it by using another TeX distribution. Which means, it can possibly fixed by updating.

However, here I can clearly see that the error goes away if you remove the `pdfusetitle` option. If this is set then hyperref tries to derive the values for `pdftitle` and `pdfauthor` from `\title` and `\author`. You did not set them, and it seems that it's not compatible to `elsarticle`, while there's no error with `article`.

Anyway, you can fix it by removing/replacing `pdfusetitle`.

Comment: Yes It was solved. Thank you. And is there a way to remove the pdfusetitle option in directly Lyx? e.g. Writing something in the preamble?

Comment: @Terence Sure, look into Document / Settings / PDF propertiers, Hyperref support / Hyperlinks.

Comment: Worked like magic.

Comment: To do this with a standard editor, have a look at [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211490/34551). You can add to hyperref the parameters `[pdfusetitle, pdfauthor={Michael Shell, My institution}]` as well to cerrect this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to actually add a PDF title and author.
Go to Document -> Settings -> PDF Properties and type a title/author under "Header Information".