# IEEEtran class, conference option and pdfusetitle in hyperref

Tags: errors, hyperref, ieeetran, stack

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage
%[pdfusetitle]
{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\title{A simple test}
\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell}
\IEEEauthorblockA{My institution}
}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

It is a correct use of the class `IEEEtran`, with the correct way to put the author and his institution in the `conference` mode of this class. This code can be compiled and provide the expected result.

However, if one uncomment the `[pdfusetitle]` line (which is a perfectly valid option of hyperref), one get a `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].`

Does that deserve a bug report to the author or am I missing something ? Noting is said in the official documentation of IEEEtran regarding that option.

=============

Configuration :

- TeX Live 2014
- pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15
- IEEEtran 2014/09/17 V1.8a
- hyperref 2012/11/06 v6.83m

Comment: Use `ieeeconf` anyways.

Comment: 1) Why? 2) `IEEETran` last update: [September 17, 2014](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/), `IEEEconf` last update: [2009-04-05](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEconf/). 3) The conf. I'd like to submit to says that the article should be written "in the IEEE Proceedings 2-column 10pt", and I think it is safer to respect this indication.

Comment: 1) Well, remove the conference mode and try again. Conference mode is implemented not so nicely. `ieeeconf.cls` is usually shipped with each conference these days. Don't ask me why. Probably they also think the same way as I. 2) That doesn't mean it's improved. 3) They don't care. Conference submissions do not go through a copy editor. It's published as is.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @percusse. I finally managed to understand *why* this happens, so I'll answer my own question, but that does not mean that I won't use ieeeconf in the future!

Comment: There is no way, that `hyperref` can know *each* class and each markup that might be used inside `\author`. The PDF format only allows a plain text string. There are lots of possibilities, how a user might want to fill the PDF author field. Examples: `Michael Shell, My institution`, `Michael Shell at My institution`, `Michael Shell (My institution)`, `Michael Shell`, `M. Shell`, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Solution:**

Simply add

```
pdfauthor={Michael Shell, My institution}
```

to the options of hyperref, i.e.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage
[pdfusetitle, pdfauthor={Michael Shell, My institution}]
{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\title{A simple test}
\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell}
\IEEEauthorblockA{My institution}
}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

gives what you want.

---

### **Explanation:**

So I wrote to Michael Shell°, the maintainer of ieeetran, who kindly answered my question

> When I finally found out what the pdfusetitle option does (it doesn't
>   seem to be mentioned in the hyperref manual, only the README), I'm not
>   at all surprised it fails.
>
> A long time ago I was forced into accepting the fact that for IEEE
>   related work, simple names in \author were not enough. And so under
>   IEEEtran \author contains more than just mere names, but also multiple
>   groups of affiliations, addresses, etc. Hyperref cannot handle this
>   (likely due to trying to import the \IEEEauthorblockN/A as some sort
>   of mere font style) and it errors out.
>
> This issue will likely arise under any class file that has additional
>   information within \author. And how is hyperref to know in every case
>   what it has to do to extract the needed information? It would also
>   have to handle/avoid features like \IEEEmembership, \IEEEauthorrefmark
>   and \IEEEcompsocitemizethanks.

In the bare_adv.tex file, `hyperref` is loaded as follows:

```
\newcommand\MYhyperrefoptions{bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,
pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels=true,
colorlinks=true,linkcolor={black},citecolor={black},urlcolor={black},
pdftitle={Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Computer Society Journals},%<!CHANGE!
pdfsubject={Typesetting},%<!CHANGE!
pdfauthor={Michael D. Shell},%<!CHANGE!
pdfkeywords={Computer Society, IEEEtran, journal, LaTeX, paper,
             template}}%<^!CHANGE!

\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\usepackage[\MYhyperrefoptions,pdftex]{hyperref}
\else
\usepackage[\MYhyperrefoptions,breaklinks=true,dvips]{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\fi
```

° He does have a stackexchange account, but with regard to IEEEtran support, just answer emails and comp.text.tex.

Comment: This information should be added to instructions for using the IEEETrans class. the error in no way aids troubleshooting

Answer (score 4):

Another solution to avoid the problem explained by Clément is to use

```
\texorpdfstring{DOCUMENT_TEXT}{PDF_TEXT}
```

The content of the first argument will make its way directly in the document and the second corresponds to the field in the pdf meta information section.

Your example could then look like

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage
[pdfusetitle]
{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\title{A simple test}
\author{%
    \texorpdfstring{%
        \IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell}
        \IEEEauthorblockA{My institution}
    }{%
        Michael Shell, My institution%
    }%
}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The same can also be applied to other fields (like `\title`).

Personally, I prefer this solution, because then I have all the information at one place (without the need of introducing any command).